# Why my url in "not matching any url" when it is? I have no idea how to fix it, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-class-based-views

Im not gonna lie, this doesnt make any sense to me, why is this trying to access 'post-details' instead of 'create-post' and how do I fix it? Thank you in advance

error:

**NoReverseMatch at /create/
Reverse for 'post-details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/post/$']
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
Django Version:     3.2.2
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'post-details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/post/$']**

Post create view:

```
class PostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm
    template_name = 'post/post_create.html'
    context_object_name = 'form'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user.profile
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'post'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/post/', views.PostDetails.as_view(), name='post-details'),
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('comment-delete/<pk>/', views.CommentDelete.as_view(), name='comment-delete'),
    path('comment-update/<pk>/', views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='comment-update'),
    path('tag/<str:name>/', views.PostTagList.as_view(), name='tag-posts'),
    path('create/', views.PostCreate.as_view(), name='create-post')
]
```

post_create.html file from my PostCreate view:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">

        <form action="" class="commenting-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.tags }}

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Edit comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.body }}
                    {{ form.picture }}
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Edit comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <hr>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'post:post-details' post_slug %}">Back</a>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

How im passing the slug value to the 'post-details'

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Latest Posts -->
        <main class="posts-listing col-lg-8">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    {% for post in posts %}
                        <div class="post col-xl-6">
                            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <a href="{% url 'post:post-details' post.slug %}">
                                    <img src="{{ post.picture.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid post-picture">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-details">
                                <div class="post-meta d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="date meta-last">{{ post.created|timesince }}</div>
                                    <div class="category">
                                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                                        <a href="#">{{ tag }} </a>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <a href="post.html"></a>
                                <p class="text-muted">{{ post.body }}</p>
                                <div class="post-footer d-flex align-items-center"><a href="#"
                                                                                      class="author d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="avatar"><img src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" alt="..." class="img-fluid"></div>
                                    <div class="title"><span>{{ post.author }}</span></div>
                                </a>

                                    <div class="comments meta-last"><i class="icon-comment"></i>{{ post.get_comment_number }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}


                </div>
                <!-- Pagination -->
                

            </div>
        </main>

        {% include 'sidebar.html' with common_tags=common_tags latest_posts=latest_posts %}
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: How are you passing the value of `post_slug` to the html template?

Comment: is this what you asked for?

Comment: No.  The `post_create.html` template has this line near the bottom: `<a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'post:post-details' post_slug %}">Back</a>` How are you passing post_slug to this template?

Comment: Oh my god, you are right, Im not passing this, thank you, its fixed